# iOS 7 adhoc build installation hangs with installing message

Tags: iphone, ios7, xcode5, armv7, ad-hoc-distribution

When building the app I added the valid architectures architecture as armv6, armv7, armvs7 and architectures as standard architecture (armv7 and armv7s). Also switched the build active architecture only to NO. Adhoc installation hangs with the status installing message (attached screenshot). I have added the UDIDs properly and was successfully able to push builds like this to those devices prior to iOS 7. This is reproducible with 4 devices so I believe this is something to do with the way I am building this. All the phones uses latest iOS 7.0.2. Additionally I tried to make the target os to iOS 7 and added arm64 to valid architectures. Still no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that since iOS7 apple blocked API access to UDID.

In other words: the applications formly used to send UDID no longer valid, and you should use iTunes to find out your and your friends UDID.

Comment: He said *I have added the UDIDs properly...*, and you can still get UDID-s with iPhone Configuration Profiles

Comment: Thanks. That particular device is apparently was not there in the previos version and the UDID is taken from the app as you have mentioned.

Comment: This is false. I just used a third party application to check this and it was the same UDID to the T

Comment: I can confirm that the UDID gained from an application is invalid (will begin with a lot of F's). The valid UDID has to be obtained from iTunes. Such a damn pain, client testing was delayed for days because of this silly roadblock. All of this pointless red tape, on top of XCode, has turned me off native iOS development.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so there is a lot of possible solutions to the problem. Here is one thread.
https://discussions.apple.com/message/23033175#23033175

Another thing you can check is to see if the wireless connection you used when first installing the ad hoc distribution is if the wireless network setting block cookies and filter multicast were turned on. If so that can cause this issues. I have found that a lot of corporate networks can have this turned on.