# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.2 Application Center

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I'm facing a problem with IBM Application Center, the internal app store for app test. 
I've installed the iOS client app after signing it with its Enteprise provisioning profile. 
It means that I can choose the apps that I want to install, by the IBM Application Center client app.
I can't understand why I can't install some iOS apps, by the AC client app. The installation fails without a meaningful error message. The strange thing is that some app can be installed but others just fails.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please give the error message which you are getting?
Also is the app downloading or while installing is it giving any error message?
If the app is downloading and while installing if you are getting error message means there is a problem with the provisioning.

All the iOS apps which is provisioned by enterprise license can be installed via AC client app. there is no restriction for some Apps.

Comment: May 12 19:26:10 iPhone installd[31] <Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008012
May 12 19:26:10 iPhone installd[31] <Error>: 0x2ff82000 install_embedded_profile: Could not install embedded profile: 0xe8008012

Comment: Did you saw this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980783/ad-hoc-ios-ipa-file-wont-install-for-devices-added-to-profile-since-ios-7-came)? i guess you are still using the developer license. 0xE8008012 is "The UUID of the device does not match any in the Provisioning Profile being loaded". Try to delete your certs and do it from scratch. if you are using enterprise edition you wont get this error. you can install apps in any ios devices if you were using enterprise certs.

Comment: This app was signed by a developer profile, then re-signed by the distribution profile (enterprise program) using Xcode's Organizer. Is it supported this case by Application Center ?

Comment: SO there might be a problem in ur Re-singing process. Follow process from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222946/how-to-find-out-what-profile-was-used-for-building-ipa-file) and find out whether your IPA is signed by enterprise profile or not.